# Disable Kafka Session Timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am trying to step though the source code of Apache Camel to identify the source of a bug. I keep getting this error despite having configured a `StringDeserializer` for the consumer:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert key of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in key.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
```

When I try to step through Camel to try to figure out how the deserialized String is still ending up as a byte array, Camel keeps on shutting itself down because the Coordinator thinks the Consumer is dead:

```
20:45:04.171 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | rtp-creditor-receive-payment] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=rtp-creditor-receive-payment] Marking the coordinator rtp-demo-cluster-kafka-0.rtp-demo-cluster-kafka-brokers.rtp-reference.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead
```

How do I completely disable all timeouts so that I can step through the source code without worrying about the consumer getting marked as dead?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you dont specify a key serializer when putting messages and try to deserialize with StringDeserializer and becasue key serialized as byte array it cant be deserialized with StringDeserializer. So you should specify StringSerializer on producer side.

Comment: @alper I wish that were the case, but the string is being serialized just fine. The same topic can be consumed by other non-camel consumers just fine.

Comment: you could set timeouts in order to avoid being kicked, but I propose you other way around. create a parallel thread and pass him the reference of your consumer. in that thread, loop indefinitely, calling to poll() in intervals (each 30 seconds, f.e). Debug your other thread meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Though you cannot disable all timeouts between a Kafka cluster and its consumers, you can modify a few properties to be very long:

- `group.max.session.timeout.ms` - This is the max session timeout for any consumer. The default is five minutes. Set this to around max integer, such as `2100000000`, in the broker properties file usually named `server.properties`.
- `max.poll.interval.ms` - This is similar to the session timeout, and will mark a consumer as dead if there is no poll within this interval. Set this to a value less than `request.timeout.ms` as well, such as `1900000000`.

From Apache Camel, you'll want to set the following properties:

- `consumerRequestTimeoutMs` - This is the max time to wait for a response from the client. Set this to `2000000000`.
- `sessionTimeoutMs` - This is likely the session timeout that is marking your consumer as dead. This should be set to a value less than `request.timeout.ms`. So, something like `1900000000`.

There may be a few more, [found here](http://camel.apache.org/kafka.html), any with `timeout` or `ms` would be good ones to look at.